# Sequence of dependent variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have a question that seems easy but I couldn't solve it.

Let $X$, $Y$ and $N$ be random variables such that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and $Y$ and $N$ are dependent.
I wonder if $X$ and $N$ has to be dependent or is it possible for them to be independent.
I think that $X$ and $N$ can be independent but couldn't find an example for this.

Would appreciate help. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $N$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ and $Y=X+N$  then $X$ and $N$  are independent but $X, X+N$ and $Y, X+N$ are both dependent.

[Note that $EXY=EX(X+N)=EX^{2}+EX EN=1$ and $EX E(X+N)=0$. So $X$ and $Y$ are not independent].

Comment: Nice example (: